# Selecting SUM of COUNT statements on 2 different tables

Tags: t-sql, count, sum, sql-server-2014

I want to SUM the COUNT values from 2 COUNT statements on different tables.
I tried:

```
SELECT(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articlegroups 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails
) 
as t
```

I tried:

```
SELECT(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articlegroups 
+
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails
) 
as t
```

I tried:

```
SELECT SUM(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articlegroups 
+
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails
) 
as t
```

I don't know what else to try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't try:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) as cnt FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM articlegroups 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM emails
) t
```

Or:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articlegroups) + 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails)  as cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articlegroups) + 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails) AS cnt
```

If either `articlegroups` or `emails` can be empty, then you should also use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articlegroups),0) + 
       COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails),0) AS cnt
```

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Yes, I know. I posted my answer just before you edited yours so as to add the second option. Never mind.

Comment: I mean 'I just saw', not 'just see' :) my english is not perfect and minor mistake changed the whole meaning.